Getting the right projection and resolution when importing from ArcGIS REST on QGIS
I imported this layer on QGIS from ArcGIS REST Services, but it has no defined CRS. In my previous question I was suggested to provide the correct dimensions in order to export this raster with correct projection, but I can't figure what are these dimensions. In the raster's page it provides the extent in cylindrical equal area, pixel size and the max number of lines and columns, so I added this information.

But when I try to export it, the program closes.
I don't know neither if I am getting the correct projection and resolution nor if I am doing something wrong that causes the program to crash.
Does anyone have any idea?
(I would also prefer to work with EPSG 4326)

I should start by saying I am using QGIS 3.36.2-Maidenhead. If you are not using this version, your results may vary.
There are a few potential issues here. It looks like you are trying to save the entire raster extent to a disk file. Even at the stated resolution, you would be downloading over 5 gigapixels of data. It's not surprising that QGIS fails to do this.
Further, in the layer metadata, the maxDownloadSizeLimit is set to 2048. This is documented in the ArcGIS API here:
"maxDownloadSizeLimit": <maxDownloadSizeLimit>, //Optional. The maximum size of download raster request that the service allows per request

The layer projection is "Cylindrical_Equal_Area_45", documented here. It's not a predefined coordinate reference system in QGIS, though. When I re-imported layers I exported for testing, I had to set the CRS manually. If you really need EPSG:4326/WGS84, you can re-project the layer. I did try setting the CRS to 4326 in the Save Raster Layer As... window, but haven't validated that it does what you want.
Setting the layer CRS to EPSG:for a raster exported to EPSG:4326 resulted in a crash.
When I tried to export using the "Create VRT" option, QGIS returned the error "Cannot write raster. Error code: destination provider"
Exporting a smaller portion of the raster by setting the Map Canvas Extent (Extensão da tela do mapa), with VRT disabled, I was able to download a raster file as a TIFF. Unfortunately, the saved raster does not appear to contain the metadata encoding land cover types.

Perhaps someone else with more knowledge of QGIS can explain how to preserve the band properties. But I think the main issue is that you are trying to download a very large raster when it is (1) not permitted and (2) may exceed the capabilities of the application/computer.

thanks! reducing the extent enabled downloading it, although the metadata does not come along.
I now noticed it is a "singleband color data", which means it's just an image.
Now I've got to figure if it's possible to convert it to raster categories.
Anyway, thanks a lot!

I noticed the same problem, and looked around a little for a solution, but didn't see anything that would help.
I found it interesting that apparently the data are licensed permissively - "This work is licensed under a Creative Commons by Attribution (CC BY 4.0) license."
So there shouldn't be anything intentionally blocking you from copying the data.

yeah right? I'm finding this whole thing quite strange
